link in mathjax align environment (github flavoured markdown)
When justifying a math statement, I often use the following pattern:
\begin{align*}
ax^2 + bx + c &= 0\\
x &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} & \text{applying the Quadratic Formula}
\end{align*}

I've tried to do this in github flavoured markdown using a link to a page explaining the process, like this:
\begin{align*}
ax^2 + bx + c &= 0\\
x &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} & \text{by the [Quadratic Formula](link/to/formula)}
\end{align*}

Unfortunately this seems to break the align environment, and now the render of this .md file shows the latex code as plaintext. Is there a way around this? I've tried a relative link, normal links and a number of other solutions. If possible, I would like to continue using the align environment with a link of some sort within the align environment.
If it's relevant, I'm doing this on a github-wiki page and both the page doing the linking, and the linked page are present in the wiki.

You can use the \href{} LaTeX macro to add a link:
\begin{align*}
ax^2 + bx + c &= 0\\
x &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} & \text{by the }\href{link/to/formula}{\text{Quadratic Formula}}
\end{align*}

The reason that your approach failed is that when Markdown converts the [Quadratic Formula](link/to/formula) to a link, that inserts HTML tags into the formula, and MathJax can't process math that has HTML tags in it.

EDIT
Here is a live example showing how this works:


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

\begin{align*}
ax^2 + bx + c &= 0\\
x &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} & \text{by the }\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function}{\text{Quadratic Formula}}
\end{align*}




\href doesn't seem to work correctly either. As soon as the link is found to be valid, the align environment ceases to render properly.

@kipawaa, I don't quite understand what you are describing.  What do you mean by "as soon as the link is found to be valid"?  Can you give an example of what you tried?

with $$ \begin{align*} ax^2 + bx + c &= 0\\ x &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} & \href{test} \end{align*} $$ it renders the equation correctly, but href is highlighted red to indicate an error (the link cannot be found). Changing the link text to \href{https://google.com} the link renders correctly, but the align environment breaks entirely, and the latex is rendered as plaintext

Neither of your examples is a correct usage of \href, as it takes two arguments, not one.  The first is the URL for the link, and the second is the text for the link.  So \href{https://google.com}{Google} would make the word "Google" be a link to the google URL given.  Note that the red  \href does not indicate that the link can't be found, as a red macro name usually means the macro is not defined.  It may be that GitHub has disabled the \href macro for security reasons.

I've added live example that you can run to see how this should work.

Thank you for the live example. It seems github doesn't allow href. not sure how to get around that, but I'll keep searching
